# How to insert second y-axis in the secong plot using `facet_grid`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a new y-axis on the right side of my second graph to better visualize the difference between them. I've seen some tips and answers, but none of them helped me solve my problem.

Here is my plot

[image]

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = agrup, y = valores, fill = CLASSI_FIN),color="transparent",
position = "dodge",stat="identity") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +  
  facet_grid(~var) +
  scale_fill_manual("",c("SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada"), values = c("dodgerblue3","gold"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom") +
        labs(x="",y="")
```

Any hint on how can I do that?

My data:

```
dat = data.frame(agrup = as.factor(c("1ª a 11ª SE", "12ª a 16ª SE", "17ª a 21ª SE", "22ª a 26ª SE",  "1ª a 11ª SE", "12ª a 16ª SE", "17ª a 21ª SE", "22ª a 26ª SE")),
                 CLASSI_FIN = c("SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada",
                                "SRAG-não especificada","SRAG-não especificada","SRAG-não especificada","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID",
                                "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada","SRAG-não especificada","SRAG-não especificada",
                                "SRAG-não especificada"), 
                 valores = c(10,121,278,924,358,1373,1146,832,2,26,49,110,18,177,166,106), 
                 var = c("Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados", "Número de Internados",
                         "Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos","Número de Óbitos"))
```

Comment: you need to use `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis() )` and make a transformation of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with secondary axis is that you need to transform your data first to match the first axis' scale and then supply the inverse transform as the argument to the secondary axis. In the example below, I'm transforming `valores* 8`, so the secondary transform should be `.x / 8`.

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = agrup, 
               y = ifelse(var == "Número de Internados", valores, valores * 8),
               fill = CLASSI_FIN),color="transparent",
           position = "dodge",stat="identity") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +  
  facet_grid(~var) +
  scale_fill_manual("",c("SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada"), values = c("dodgerblue3","gold"))+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x / 8)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom") +
  labs(x="",y="")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a duplicate of the y-scale you can use: `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())`

Comment: Using this I got a second axis, but m second grapic didn't  follow it.